# Solve the syntax error with Redshift operator does not exist and add explicit casts

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I am a newbie in the area of redshift data modeling and got myself into trouble with an error.ERROR:

**--Final version**

> **syntax error ERROR:** **operator does not exist**: **text | record Hint: No**
> operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to
> add explicit type casts. Where: SQL statement "SELECT 'create temp
> table ' || $1 || ' as select * from' | $2 |" PL/pgSQL function "egen"
> line 36 at execute statement [ErrorId:
> 1-61dc32bf-0a451f5e2c2639235abb8876]

I am trying to do a simple transformation that gets returned in output when the procedure is called. (As of now I got to find from the documentation we have to use either temp table or cursors to achieve this)

Pseudocode:

- I am trying to restrict data to its latest one in (2019)  Get the
- list of managers create columns if a person is a manager or not from the list.
- Return it as a result

Data looks as follows Employee [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0nMY.png)

My Select query works fine out of the procedure, please find my complete code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EGEN(tmp_name INOUT varchar(256) )

AS $$
DECLARE 
--As i have less data  managed to create it as an array or please use temp or table and join it with the actual query to perform transformation
MGR_RECORD RECORD;
DATAS RECORD;

item_cnt int := 0;
V_DATE_YEAR int := 0;

BEGIN 

--EXECUTE (select  cast(extract(year from current_date) as integer)-3) INTO V_DATE_YEAR;
--Manager Records are stored here below
SELECT DISTINCT   managerid from "dev"."public"."emp_salary" INTO MGR_RECORD;
SELECT  employeeid,
            managerid,
            promotion,
            q_bonus,
            d_salary,
            case  when contractor = 'x' 
                then 'TemporaryEmployee' 
                else 'PermanentEmployee' 
                END    as EmployeeType,
    -- IFstatement not supported under select query         
            case when employeeid in (select distinct managerid FROM "dev"."public"."emp_salary" )
            then 'Manager'
            else 'Ordinary FTE'
            END as FTETYPE 

            FROM "dev"."public"."emp_salary" where  cast(extract(year from promotion) as int )  >= 2019 into DATAS;
        
        
 
--COMMIT; 
  tmp_name := 'ManagerUpdatedTable';
  EXECUTE 'drop table if exists ' || tmp_name;
  EXECUTE 'create temp table ' || 'ManagerUpdatedTable' || ' as select * from' |DATAS| ;


END;
 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

-- Call tests CALL EGEN('myresult'); SELECT * from myresult;

Also, additional query (Can we replace )

```
case when employeeid in (select distinct managerid FROM "dev"."public"."emp_salary" )
            then 'Manager'
            else 'Ordinary FTE'
            END as FTETYPE
```

this transform in query to IF , if possible please provide details.

Thanks and Regards,
Gabby

Comment: you use badly operator `|`. For string concatenation you need to use operator `||`. And using concatenation of string ` .. as select * from` | DATAS` looks strange too. You cannot to read data from record variable. Variable is not table.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, So how can we achieve this solution, when I had to read data from a table output? Can you please provide an alternative logic or solution to solve this issue? thanks and regards G

Comment: You should to use `EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE t INSERT INTO SELECT $1.f1, $1.f2,...' USING recvar`. But I am not an expert on redshift, because it is based on age old Postgres. So maybe `USING clause` is not available there, and everything have to be done by using string op